# What does it mean you are where you think you are

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe, baal-shem-tov, baal-hatanya

BH

I heard and correct me if I’m wrong, that the Baal Shem Tov said that you are where you think you are so if you're thinking about inyanim of Atzilut you there, even though - correct me if I’m wrong - the nefesh Bahamis is in Assiya and the sechel is also in Assiya?

Someone told me some of these concepts are in:
Source:ch. 6,7 Likkutei Amarim/Sefer Shel Beinonim by the Alter Rebbe

Comment: https://chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/1/56.htm

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/livingtorah/player_cdo/aid/3226536/jewish/Thought-for-the-Day.htm

Answer (score 2):

The spiritual worlds aren’t physical, you can’t travel there. Sounds obvious but if so then what does it mean to be a world? Short way of describing it is paradigm of thinking, or your base assumptions. So the way you think is “where” you are

Comment: Please cite a source for the positive things you've claimed

Comment: Interesting like the spiritual worlds are always here around us and by negating anything physical you inevitability position your self in that location of the higher spiritual part of you something like that?